# there are two questions about join query

Tags: rdbms

The result of any join query generated is a permanent table? true or false
I got this question in one of my exam and I marked it as false but was evaluated wrong.please clarify my doubt about this

Comment: My answer to the the question would also be "false". Without more context it is hard to tell why this answer should be wrong. You should ask the examiner who corrected the exam why this is wrong.

Comment: actually that was mine online exam somewhere, so i dont hve any option of asking the examiner.. anyways thank you